# Robotium - Waiting for an Activity's tasks to complete

Tags: java, android, testing, robotium

I've just started learning to use Robotium for testing my app. I have written a test case that resets a list of stats, and then checks if the values are equal to 0. The code is below:

```
public void testClearStats() {
    solo.clickOnButton("Clear Stats");
    solo.clickOnButton("Yes");
    TextView views = (TextView) solo.getView(R.id.textViewsNum);
    TextView prompts = (TextView) solo.getView(R.id.textPromptsNum);
    TextView completions = (TextView) solo.getView(R.id.textCompleteNum);
    assertEquals("0", views.getText().toString());
    assertEquals("0", prompts.getText().toString());
    assertEquals("0", completions.getText().toString());
}
```

The test was failing when it shouldn't because it was checking the values of the TextViews before their results were reset. To get around this, I added this line:

```
solo.waitForActivity(solo.getCurrentActivity().toString());
```

With this statement the test passes but it seems to take an unnecessary long time to complete. I was wondering if there was a better/correct way of way doing this, or is this the best way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to wait on something, what you choose will depend on your application and without looking at it i cannot answer what will be the best thing to wait for.

What visual indicators do you have for the reset to occur? do you have a new activity open? Is there text telling it has complete? if it is literally just the three textfields. if it is then you might manage to use solo.waitfortext("0") although the better way will be to use the new concept of conditions and use the solo.waitForCondition(method) (the condition will probably be to wait for the text to be 0, but you would have put the condition into one place and then if you later find a better way then you only have to change it once).

```
public class WaitForReset implements Condition
{

    public boolean isSatisfied()
    {
        TextView views = (TextView) solo.getView(R.id.textViewsNum);
        TextView prompts = (TextView) solo.getView(R.id.textPromptsNum);
        TextView completions = (TextView) solo.getView(R.id.textCompleteNum);
        if(isViewZero(views) && isViewZero(prompts) && isViewZero(completions))
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private isViewZero(TextView textView)
    {
        if((textView!=null) && (textView.getText().toString() ==0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then assert on the value of the waitforcondition being true!

Comment: Okay I understand the logic behind it now. However its going to be difficult to find that something to wait for. With the method solo.waitForText(), can I choose which TextView to look at specifically? I have many TextViews in this screen, and some can start with the value 0 before clearing the stats.

Comment: There is actually no indication to show that stats have been cleared, other than the values all being reset. However, if all these values are at 0 already, then you can't really tell if the test has executed correctly, as the values won't change.

Comment: You kind of answered your own issue, and also why in TDD you have test fail before getting them to pass, you need to ensure that your indicator actually changes so you should make sure values are not 0 before you reset otherwise you will never be sure. That is kind of an issue with your test as a whole rather than robotium though. As for the waiting part, I will add in some code to help you!

Comment: I hate to prompt you but if my answer solved your issue can you accept it by pressing the tick? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use waitForActivity and choose a specific timeout.`solo.waitForActivity(YourActivity.class, timeout);`

Comment: It doesn't make sense - wait for current actvitiy